# Ordering and creating an Unix file

Tags: unix

I have an data file in Unix which contains the following records:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6

I will pass a parameter based on which a new file should be created. For example, it the parameter value is 2, the new file will be:

> 1 2
>
> 3 4
>
> 5 6

Similarly, if the parm is 3, then:

> 1 2 3
>
> 4 5 6

Can someone give me some hints on how to do this?

Thanks,
Visakh

Answer (score 2):

You can use this perl one-liner:

```
perl -e "map chomp, @a=<>; print join(' ', splice @a,0,2).$/ while @a;" <(seq 6)
# 1 2
# 3 4
# 5 6

perl -e "map chomp, @a=<>; print join(' ', splice @a,0,3).$/ while @a;" <(seq 6)
# 1 2 3
# 4 5 6
```

This you can easily incorporate into a shell script:

```
n=3
perl -e "map chomp, @a=<>; print join(' ', splice @a,0,$n).$/ while @a;" <file>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# formatter.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $newlineCnt = $ARGV[1];
if (! defined $newlineCnt) { $newlineCnt = 1; }

my $idx = 0;
while (<>) {
    if ($idx == $newlineCnt) { print "\n"; $idx = 0; }
    $idx++;
    print "$_ ";
}
```

On the command line, leaving out the parameter defaults to `1`:

```
$ formatter.pl < testData.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

On the command line, specifying `2` as the test parameter:

```
$ formatter.pl 2 < testData.txt
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I am trying to incorporate this logic in an shell script which has other statements as well as DB queries. I will try this over there and see whether it works fine. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Alex, do you have any suggestions without using Perl?

Comment: You could use the code I provided to learn to write a script in a language of your choice. It's a pretty straightforward process. If you write something, feel free to edit your question and we can help troubleshoot problems with it, if you like.